# How to reduce color space in a post-processing material in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: color, post-processing, unreal

I'm trying to get an old-school Quake 1 look going in UE4.

I am currently using this blueprint in order to get a retro style large pixel filter.

[image: blueprint for large pixel post-processing filter]

In game (might need to zoom in to see the difference):

[image]

The look I am going for now is a low color depth (8 bit etc) that old games such as Quake had. Here is a picture for reference.

[image]

Is there any way I can reduce the color space through either a post-processing volume itself or a post-processing material?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

Download the default color LUT from [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/ColorGrading/index.html). Open it in Photoshop (or equivilant) and use posterize to reduce the colors. Then take that and use it as a LUT for your post-processing volume.

Here was my outcome:

[image]